# Can I sign git commits with keybase.io?

Tags: git, gnupg, keybase

I am setting up a new machine and would prefer to use keybase for various pgp activities like signing commits. I can run a command like

```
$ keybase pgp sign -m foo > x
$ gpg --verify x 2>&1 | grep -oF 'Good signature'
Good signature
```

I could sign things directly with gpg, but it's convenient to let keybase manage the thing. So can I somehow make git use keybase?

[Git configuration](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Configuration) doesn't seem to have a way to customize the gpg command that it uses to sign commits. All you can do is provide the key. Is there any way to do it?

Comment: i stopped using the keybase when zoom bought it. if you want to host your prox and use the git https://github.com/woss/git-pgp-remote-sign

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to the link in [Xavier's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58442385/418413) I learned that I can override the gpg program with the gpg.program configuration:

```
git config --global gpg.program /path/to/something
```

So I can use this to write a wrapper around keybase.

But git is, as it turns out, pretty finicky about what that `something` is. [Git expects to partially parse](https://github.com/git/git/blob/3034dab9ed6b11970a53099a7b3ca981f1461365/gpg-interface.c#L318) the output that results from the `--fd-status` flag, which causes `gpg` to output [special status codes](https://git.gnupg.org/cgi-bin/gitweb.cgi?p=gnupg.git;a=blob;f=doc/DETAILS;hb=HEAD#l323) at an alternate filehandle.

Fortunately, at least for my first pass, git doesn't parse *everything* that gpg produces, so I was able to emulate it. [Here's a gist with a functional wrapper](https://gist.github.com/kojiromike/0f5d5f2a24b2f6c10e95d18779fa0a87), and here's the meat of it:

```sh
# Copy the commit message from stdin to a file. 
d=$(mktmp -d "${TMPDIR:-/tmp}/gitsig.XXXXXXXXX")
cat > "$d/commit.msg"

# Have Keybase write the signature to another file.
keybase pgp sign --detached \
                 --key "$1" \
                 --infile "$d/commit.msg" \
                 --outfile "$d/commit.sig"

# Have gpg verify the signature right away.
# Capture its status in a file.
gpg --verify --status-fd=2 \
    "$d/commit.sig" "$d/commit.msg" \
    > /dev/null 2> "$d/gpgstatus.txt"

# Copy the KEY_CONSIDERED lines to stderr. Git wants that.
grep '^\[GNUPG:\] KEY_CONSIDERED' "$d/gpgstatus.txt" >&2

# Produce a minimal SIG_CREATED line to stderr. Git also wants that.
printf '[GNUPG:] SIG_CREATED ' >&2
```

Comment: It is awesome that you did this! That said, by showing me the complex and brittle solution required for direct signing with keybase you've convinced me to just use gnupg :)

Answer (score 1):

There is a doc here on how to do it (with github) https://github.com/pstadler/keybase-gpg-github

Comment: That tells me there's a `gpg.program`, which is super helpful. However, overriding this program is not trivial because in [version 2.10](https://github.com/git/git/blob/53f9a3e157dbbc901a02ac2c73346d375e24978c/Documentation/RelNotes/2.10.0.txt#L183) git implemented support for `gpg --status-fd`, which takes precedence over the unix exit status of gpg. Unfortunately, I haven't figured out the magic status output git expects gpg to give it to accept the signature output yet. This may take some time...